# DRF: Serialization with cross reference table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have 3 models, the first one contains controller names and their IDs, the second measurements and their IDs and the third has foreign keys to both and is used as a cross-reference based on IDs.
With the following serializer and view I can have my API return the measurements each controller has.

Serializer:

```
class MeasurementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # used in stationsMeasurementsInfo view
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = Measurements
        fields = ['code', 'measurement', 'unit', 'type']
```

View:

```
class stationsMeasurementsInfo(generics.ListAPIView):
    #returns the measurements a station tracks
    #authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    #permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = MeasurementsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        source = self.kwargs['sourceName']
        name = self.kwargs['stationName']


        final = Measurements.objects.filter(microcontrollersmeasurements__microcontroller__name=name)

        return final

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(stationsMeasurementsInfo, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.data = {"source": self.kwargs['sourceName'],
                    "stations": [{
                        "station": self.kwargs['stationName'],
                        "measurements": res.data
                    }
                    ]
                    }
        return res
```

The problem is that I cannot actually retrieve the name of the controller, currently, I manually insert it into the list which means that I cannot retrieve the measurements of multiple controllers with a single API call. How would I go about fixing this issue?

EDIT:

Models:

```
class Microcontrollers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    software = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    date_installed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_battery_last_replaced = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    private = models.IntegerField()
    datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTime_Updated')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'microcontrollers'
        verbose_name_plural = "Microcontrollers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.friendly_name

class Measurements(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTime_Updated')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'measurements'

    datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTime_Updated')  # Field name made lowercase.

class MicrocontrollersMeasurements(models.Model):
    microcontroller = models.ForeignKey(Microcontrollers, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurements, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateTime_Updated')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'microcontrollers_measurements'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.measurement.measurement
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code of the models? At least the cross-reference model and the controller one.

Comment: I have edited the post to include all 3 of them

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think one-to-many relation between Microcontroller and Measurement would be better for this situation - by logic, you can't have one masurement for many microcontrollers.

Your models names should by singular like `Microcontroller`, `Measurement`.

If you still wants to stay with this relations, this solution should work:

Add many to many field to `Measurements` model.

```
microcontrollers = models.ManyToManyField(
    Microcontrollers,
    related_name="measurements",
    through='yourapp.MicrocontrollersMeasurements',
    through_fields=('measurement', 'microcontroller')
)
```

Update your `MeasurementsSerializer`

```
class MeasurementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
   
    microcontrollers = MicrocontrollerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Measurements
        fields = ['code', 'measurement', 'unit', 'type', 'microcontrollers']
```

Remember to `prefetch_related('microcontrollers')` for better database query performance.